# Cannot compile PLSQL procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, infinite-loop

This procedure updates a table where I keep track of a (very-basic) historical work done. The problem is that I can't modify it or compile it anymore. I don't know if I'm making a mistake in the procedure and an infinite-loop is going on. My DBA has checked the procedure and everything's seems right, but I still can't change it, use it.

My bet is that when I'm trying to catch the exception and I use the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL` the loop gets stuck.

Any advise?

Cheers

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DOACTUALIZARHISTORIALEM 
(
  QUSUARIO IN VARCHAR2  
, QARCHIVO IN VARCHAR2  
, QANIOFISCAL IN VARCHAR2
, QFECHAPROCESAMIENTO IN DATE
) AS 

  cursorEstatus SYS_REFCURSOR;

  sqlQueryA VARCHAR2(200);
  sqlQueryB VARCHAR2(200);
  idArchivo INTEGER;

  idPrograma VARCHAR2(10);
  idComponente VARCHAR2(10);

  sumaSolicitado DECIMAL;
  sumaAprobado DECIMAL;
  sumaPagado DECIMAL;

BEGIN

  idArchivo := getidarchivo(qarchivo,getidusuario(qusuario),qaniofiscal);

  sqlQueryA := 'SELECT programa, componente'||
                ' FROM '||qusuario||
              ' WHERE id_archivo = :1';

  OPEN cursorEstatus FOR sqlQueryA USING idArchivo;
  LOOP
    FETCH cursorEstatus INTO idPrograma, idComponente;
    EXIT WHEN cursorEstatus%NOTFOUND;

    BEGIN  
      sqlQueryB := 'SELECT sum(monto_federal) '||
                    ' FROM '||qusuario||
                   ' WHERE programa = :1'||
                    ' AND componente = :2'||
                    ' AND estatus_monto = 1'||
                    ' AND status = 1';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQueryB
        INTO sumaSolicitado
        USING idPrograma, idComponente;

        INSERT INTO src_historialem VALUES (idArchivo,
                                            qfechaprocesamiento,
                                            idPrograma,
                                            idComponente,
                                            1,
                                            sumaSolicitado);
        COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
      END;

    BEGIN
      sqlQueryB := 'SELECT sum(monto_federal) '||
                    ' FROM '||qusuario||
                   ' WHERE programa = :1'||
                    ' AND componente = :2'||
                    ' AND estatus_monto = 2'||
                    ' AND status = 1';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQueryB
        INTO sumaAprobado
        USING idPrograma, idComponente;


        INSERT INTO src_historialem VALUES (idArchivo,
                                            qfechaprocesamiento,
                                            idPrograma,
                                            idComponente,
                                            2,
                                            sumaSolicitado);
        COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
      END;

    BEGIN
      sqlQueryB := 'SELECT sum(monto_federal) '||
                    ' FROM '||qusuario||
                   ' WHERE programa = :1'||
                    ' AND componente = :2'||
                    ' AND estatus_monto = 3'||
                    ' AND status = 1';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQueryB
        INTO sumaPagado
        USING idPrograma, idComponente;


        INSERT INTO src_historialem VALUES (idArchivo,
                                            qfechaprocesamiento,
                                            idPrograma,
                                            idComponente,
                                            3,
                                            sumaSolicitado);
        COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
      END;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cursorEstatus;
END DOACTUALIZARHISTORIALEM;
```

Comment: What do you mean that you can't compile it any more?  Are you saying that when you compile it you get errors?  If so, what errors?  Are you saying that the procedure compiles but it runs forever when you execute it?  That it throws errors when you execute it?  Something else?

Comment: When I compile it via SqlPlus no errors, no warnings, just after a very long time it sends the timeout. When the procedure gets called from the webApp, the same, no errors, no warnings. Tried to drop it and the same, gives timeout after a long time to just not drop it.

Comment: What does "sends the timeout" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object TEST.DOACTUALIZARHISTORIALEM

Comment: OK.  So you are getting an error.  Is some other session executing this procedure?

Comment: Nope. Checked that with my DBA and there was only one session. Killed that session thinking it could be blocking it but after killing the session the procedure still can't be compiled

Comment: While you are trying to compile the procedure, what session is your session waiting on?

Comment: How can I check that?... My DBA is not helping me as he should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open a SQL*Plus session (session A).  Get that session's `SID` and `SERIAL#`.  Write those numbers down.

```
SELECT sid, serial#
  FROM v$session
 WHERE sid = (select distinct sid from v$mystat);
```

2) Open a second SQL*Plus session (session B) connecting to the same database as A.

3) In session A, try to compile the code

4) While that is running, in session B, run the query

```
SELECT blocking_session_status,
       blocking_instance,
       blocking_session
  FROM v$session
 WHERE sid     = <<sid from step 1>>
   AND serial# = <<serial# from step 1>>
```

That will show you the `SID` of the session that holds the lock on the procedure.  Alternately, `dba_waiters` should have similar information.

```
SELECT waiting_session,
       holding_session,
       lock_type,
       mode_held,
       mode_requested
  FROM dba_waiters
 WHERE waiting_session = <<sid from step 1>>
```

5) Once you've determined what session holds the lock, you can ask the DBA to kill the session.

Comment: I'll check it. Just one thing, could it be that my procedure creates an infinite loop, so the session  using it locks it indefinitely?

Comment: @BRabbit27 - If your session owns the lock, your session will be granted the lock immediately.  You can't lock your own session out.  It is entirely possible that your code implements an infinite loop and that, as a result, a call to the procedure would never return.  But that would be a different error.

Comment: Thanks we found the object that was blocking and it works now.